# Moving a Button using StoryBoard in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I am trying to move a Button named `btnCreate`

Here is the XAML :

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="btnCreate"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                 From="1000" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
```

Is the above `TargetProperty` correct?

I am unable to move the button from the bottom of the window to the top of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks good, you just need to add a `TranslateTransform` to your button:

```
<Button>
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform />
    </Button.RenderTransform>

    ...
</Button>
```

If you don't do this, the target property will try to change the `Y` value of a non-existent `TranslateTransform`.